# WPF Grid RowSpan layout understanding

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, grid

I have a very simple XAML

```
<ui:BorderedGrid>
        <ui:BorderedGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </ui:BorderedGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <ui:BorderedGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </ui:BorderedGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Width="200" Height="70"></StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="200" Height="300"></StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="Plum" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="200" Height="150"></StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="SaddleBrown" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Width="200" Height="250"></StackPanel>
    </ui:BorderedGrid>
```

The `BorderedGrid` is just an extended version of WPF standard `Grid`, which have overriden `OnRender` function to draw column and row lines. Following is it's implementation

```
public class BorderedGrid : Grid
    {
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            double leftOffset = 0;
            double topOffset = 0;
            System.Windows.Media.Pen pen = new System.Windows.Media.Pen(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightGray, 1);
            pen.Freeze();

            foreach (RowDefinition row in this.RowDefinitions)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(pen, new System.Windows.Point(0, topOffset), new System.Windows.Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));
                topOffset += row.ActualHeight;
            }
            // draw last line at the bottom
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new System.Windows.Point(0, topOffset), new System.Windows.Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));

            foreach (ColumnDefinition column in this.ColumnDefinitions)
            {
                dc.DrawLine(pen, new System.Windows.Point(leftOffset, 0), new System.Windows.Point(leftOffset, this.ActualHeight));
                leftOffset += column.ActualWidth;
            }
            // draw last line on the right
            dc.DrawLine(pen, new System.Windows.Point(leftOffset, 0), new System.Windows.Point(leftOffset, this.ActualHeight));

            base.OnRender(dc);
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I am assuming the output should be like this

[image: Output should be like this]

But the actual output is like this

[image]

My question is why this white space is left in first row? I think I am missing very simple thing.. :(

Comment: have you tried to remove the height of stackpanel blue ?

Comment: If I remove the height of blue stackpanel, it is not shown simply. I need it to be displayed.

Comment: here you can see your grid.row=0 space is higher so when you set the height=70 then it cover only those portion only if you increase the height or decrease the grid.row portion.

Comment: Do you need your first row to be auto-sized? You may have better luck fixing the size of that row to 70, avoiding some algebra done on the part of WPF's layout engine to figure out what you want.

Comment: @DhavalPatel, Sorry but I didn't get your point.

Comment: @DanGarant, Thanks for suggestion, but I need auto-sized row.

Answer (score 1):

All the rows need to be aligned irrespective of columns. Since the height of row 0 is auto. Its actual height becomes the height of its tallest child element + margin, which will be a portion of the plum height + 10 (from margin).

Since the height (70) of the blue panel is shorter than the height of its row (row 0) and it is vertical aligned to the top, you get the the white space below it.

I believe the result you are seeing is what is expected based on your configuration of rows, row spans, height, etc.

In a way, your horizontal grid lines already hinted at the computed row heights.

Here is another way to look at it:

Height of row 2 is height of SaddleBrown

Height of row 1 is height of row 2 minus height of Red

Height of row 0 is height of Plum minus height of row 1

Height of row 0 is great than the height of Blue. Blue is vertical aligned to the top and therefore has a white space below it.

Comment: The plum stackpanel is given a row span of 2, so the direct child is the blue stackpanel. I think it should be considered as the child to calculate height of row, Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I try not to spend too much time fighting with WPF's `Auto`. It seems like your two columns are largely independent in terms of their layout. You could do something like this, basically rendering two independent columns:

```
<ui:BorderedGrid>
        <ui:BorderedGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </ui:BorderedGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Width="200" Grid.Column="0">
            <StackPanel Background="Blue"Margin="5" Height="70"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Background="Red" Margin="5" Height="300"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="200" Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel Background="Plum" Margin="5" Height="150"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Background="SaddleBrown"Margin="5" Height="250"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
</ui:BorderedGrid>
```